# Does blocking a user block them from "Popular right now"?

Tags: youtube

I saw a certain user's video on Popular Right Now - Australia by Popular on YouTube - Australia, blocked the user, and refreshed my home page, and his video's still there.

Is this just a caching issue, or does blocking a user not affect "Popular right now"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blocking on YouTube only blocks communication between you and them, it doesn't block anything else. There are [Firefox-addons](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/video-blocker/)/[Chrome-extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/video-blocker/jknkjnpcbbgcbdbaampbjlhkcghmgfhk) around though that let you allow to block individual channels.